# How to open a database connection through "using" in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need access to database context inside my `ActionFilter` attribute. How can I do that without passing the context through the constructor?

The short question is: How to get the database context in one line as we did in the ASP.NET Framework before?

Comment: You can still use the DB Connector, instanciate it with the connection string in a using and you're good to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way would be to register your filter using dependency injection and then using the [`ServiceFilterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#servicefilterattribute) to place your filter into the pipeline. That way, your filter type will be resolved using dependency injection, so you can just inject your database context properly and use it like you normally would.

```
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public MyActionFilter(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // use _dbContext here
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    { }
}
```

Register the type in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddTransient<MyActionFilter>();
```

And then use the `ServiceFilterAttribute` to activate it. Either as an attribute on a controller or an action:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyActionFilter))]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // …
}
```

Or register it globally like any other filter via the `MvcOptions`:

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(new ServiceFilterAttribute(typeof(MyActionFilter)));
});
```

Then, the `MyActionFilter` will be resolved on each request that requires the filter, and the database context will be injected with the proper lifetime from the dependency injection container.

Instantiating the database context yourself (outside of unit tests) is generally not recommended. You have a dependency injection container in ASP.NET Core, so you should utilize it everywhere instead of maintaining object lifetimes and dependencies yourself.